# Pick out two related elements from a list using criterion

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Suppose I have a list:

$lst= \{\{k_1, g_1\},\{k_2,g_2\},...,\{k_{max},g_{max}\},...,\{k_n,g_n\}\}$

Here $\{k_{max},g_{max}\}$ is a special element, in which $g_{max}$ is the maximum of all $g_{i}$

I can use `Ordering` to find the ordering that sorts the list with respect to the second element of it sublist:

`lst[[Ordering[lst[[All, 2]]]]];`

then pick out the list having $g_{max}$ with `lst[[Ordering[lst[[All, 2]]]]][[-1]]`.

My question is how to pick out a more special list $\{k^\ast, g^\ast \}$, for example, having $g^\ast$ such that ${\rm{Abs}}[g^\ast] = 50 g_{max}$? In a real case, the equal sign may not hold exactly. In this case, I still want to find the list, which fits the relation best. It means that to find a list such that ${\rm{Abs}}[g^\ast]$ is most close to $50 g_{max}$ Here is a sample [list](https://gofile.io/?c=8sWDZR) for your experiment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html):

```
gmax = lst[[Ordering[lst[[All, 2]], -1]]][[1, -1]];

lst[[Nearest[Abs[lst[[All, 2]]] -> "Index", 50 gmax]]]
```

> {{3.75, -0.827334}}